# How to sum JTable column values and display in a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am having trouble with calculating the sum of my table column whenever a row is added or deleted. I have a button which adds a row to the table, and I want the sum of the to be automatically calculated and displayed in a text field. I have made a method `getsum` for the calculation and the am calling this method on the `actionperformed` event of the button. I am getting an error when I run the program and nothing is displayed in the text field.

[image]

Comment: code looks like good for me, but there is one problem that 1. cell can be null, 2. (then) sum = sum + parseInt...toString() can be  NPE generator, 3. JTable and its model can hold and to display the standard Java data types,

Comment: Few questions: is service_sales your class name? Class name is usually uppercase name. Shouldn't you update your bill in jButton1ActionPreformed? You just call method which returns you an integer, but don't update  your textfield.

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable / XxxTableModel stored in local variable

Comment: *"enter image description here"*  `<head-desk>` Don't post *images* of code.  Instead post code as text, and follow the sage advice of @mKorbel 
and post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: am short of ideas please kindly help rewrite my code. service_sales is the variable name for my jtable. am using netbeans to just drag components and design my jtable.

Comment: sorry Berrigan  Service_sales is my main class(ClassName) and it extendes javax.swing.JFrame

Comment: am getting this error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100.00" the value 100 is the value on the column at jtable componet 2

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`TableModelListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/tablemodellistener.html) to your table. That way, the text field will get updated every time the table's model changes.

```
model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        textField.setText(getSum());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call .setText function of the particular textField to bind the value u obtain onto it.

Comment: ttxt_total.setText(Integer.toString(getsum()));

Comment: but nothing is happening

Comment: u added that in the constructor. not in the event itself. @Emma

Comment: besides, u need to reorganize your codes properly. there is no proper flow in it @Emma